# Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,9)$ have mean $0$ and variance $9$. Find the expected value of $X^2(X+1)$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value

> Let  $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,9)$  have mean $0$ and variance $9$. Find the expected value of  $X^2(X+1)$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question if you intend to continue posting problem statement questions without your input.

Answer (score 2):

We seek the mean of $X^3+X^2$. The first term makes no contribution, because the distribution is symmetric. The second term has mean $9+0^2=9$, so the answer is $9$.

Comment: Isn't $X^2$ symmetric as well, making the expected value $0$?

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated Since $x^{3}$ is an odd function and the Gaussian is an even function, the product of the two is odd and hence the integral of their product is zero over any interval $[-a,a]$. Although $X^{2}$ is symmetric, it's the fact that it's not an odd function that matters.

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated I said the distribution was symmetric, i.e. the pdf is an even function. This ensures even functions have zero mean (or undefined mean, but that doesn't happen here). Note $\Bbb EX^2$ cannot be $0$, except for a constant variable of value $0$.

Comment: @JessicaK Sorry to step on your toes there.

Comment: @J.G. I'm the one stepping on your toes!

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. Thanks for explaining

Comment: I've just noticed a typo: "ensures even" should say "ensures odd".